# Can I print exactly representable float without loss of precision?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I am trying to print float value `299792450` with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", 299792450.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

According to [IEEE 754 Calculator](http://weitz.de/ieee/), this is exactly representable floating point value in binary32 format. However I am getting another value in output:

```
$ ./a.out 
299792448.000000
```

Why it is not equal to `299792450`? I expected it to be `299792450` because it is exactly representable and there should be no loss of precision.

Comment: How does the linked floating-point calculator show that the number is representable?

Comment: I must admit that I misused linked floating-point calculator. `299792450` is indeed not exactly representable, that's why the output differs.

Comment: As IEEE-754 float, that number gets the value 299792448. As 32 bit integer, it has  more than 24 significant bits (hex: 11DE7842, i.e. 28 significant bits -- we can do without leading and trailing zeros), so it is not exactly representable.

Comment: For fun, 299,792,458 is [c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light).  An appropriate constant  for  [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [IEEE 754 Calculator](http://weitz.de/ieee/), even in "binary32" mode, reports values as *rounded* decimal values, not exact values.

"this is exactly representable floating point value in binary32 format. " is unfounded.

Aside: [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) to print a FP *exactly*

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a `float` is a IEEE754 single precision floating point number, 299792450 **cannot** be represented exactly.

This value requires at least 28 bits of precision, but a `float` has at most 24 bits of precision.  So the value gets rounded to the closest possible value that can be represented.

If you used a `double` which has 53 bits of precision, you would see the exact value.

```
printf("%f\n", 299792450.0);
```

Comment: Or in terms of decimal digits, an IEEE-754 binary32 floating-point number has 6-7 decimal digits of precision, whereas the OP's desired number has nine significant decimal digits.

Comment: Minor quibble: [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has 6-9 decimal digits of  precision. That is why `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is 9, not 7.  OP's `299792450.0f` could be thought of as 8, 9, or 10 significant decimal digits.  Agree and UV'd your good answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But isn't 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0 representable exactly in IEEE 754 float32? You can't distinguish it from the nearest float to 3.4028235e38, so all extra digits are somehow superfluous, but the first one is the exact value, the second is not.

Comment: @chux: That is not what `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is 9. `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is the number of significant decimal digits required to guarantee a round-trip conversion from `float` to decimal and back. It is not a measure of decimal digits representable by `float` and should not be used as a gauge for such.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is 9 because in _some_ regions of `float`, the _decimal_ precision is 9.  9 being the widest case - 6, 7, 8  in other regions.  Hence 9 is the worst case needed for good round tripping from decimal-float-decimal for _all_ float as you noted.   dbush comment refers to float having "6-7"  decimal digits .  The 7 is the issue.  It should be 6-9 or simple say 6.  Precise decimal characterization of a binary `float` is itself fuzzy.

Comment: @chux: No. First, `float` does not have a “decimal precision.” Second, `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is defined by the C standard: “number of decimal digits, *n*, such that any floating-point number with *p* radix *b* digits can be rounded to a floating-point number with *n* decimal digits and back again without change to the value.” it is the number of decimal digits needed to convey a `float`, not a number of decimal digits a `float` can represent, not even when limited to a particular region.

Comment: @chux: Furthermore, the math would not work out. If there were a “region” where a binary-based `float` could faithfully record and reproduce nine decimal digits, then `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` would have to be 10, because the nature of binary floating-point is that it is not commensurate with decimal. To be able to reproduce nine decimal digits, it would have to have additional numbers in between those corresponding to specific nine-decimal-digit numbers, so, to provide the round-trip service that `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` guarantees, you would need a tenth digit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it looks like we agree a binary `float` does not precisely have a “decimal precision.” Your comment then could be addressed to then to dbush who first commented to its existence.   Folks carry a loose understanding of discussion of the “decimal precision.” of a float and that being 6 of so digits.  dbush's assertion was 6-7, mine was promoting 6-9.  yet ...

Comment: @EricPostpischil The C def of `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` is the C def, no disagreement there. The effect of that definition is due to different regions, when expressed as decimal vs binary.  The region just above 1 [1.0...] (a best case) has as "decimal precision" of about 8 (off by 1 from my earlier 9) as the next representable `float` is 1.000000119..., then 1.000000238...   My assertion of 6-9 should have been 6-8 decimal digits per your later comment.  Will be off line for the week-end -  will review any comments later.

Answer (score 1):

A `float` value doesn't have enough precision for a value like this, you need to use a `double` or, for maximum precision, a `long double`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%Lf\n", 299792450.0L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's a `long float`?  Do you mean `long double`?